# Mailchimp api v1.3 returns HTTP/1.0 302 Moved Temporarily

Tags: php, mailchimp

Some of our customers still use api v1.3. [MailChimp PHP API](https://github.com/dermidgen/mailchimp-STS-api-mini-class) Wrapper 1.3 is used. From last 10 days this stopped working for unknown reasons. I know we should upgrade to api v3, but some customers won't see our e-mail so I am trying to find out what could be wrong.

I am enclosing the part of code that is calling their server which returns "http://HTTP/1.0 302 Moved Temporarily Server: AkamaiGHost...". I am trying with their support but even they don't know anything, it would be helpful if anybody can tell any opinion what could be the reason for this response so I can push this further with their support.

```
    $dc = "us1";
    if (strstr($this->api_key, "-")) {
        list($key, $dc) = explode("-", $this->api_key, 2);
        if (!$dc)
            $dc = "us1";
    }
    $host = $dc . "." . $this->apiUrl["host"];
    $params["apikey"] = $this->api_key;

    $this->errorMessage = "";
    $this->errorCode = "";
    $sep_changed = false;
    //sigh, apparently some distribs change this to &amp; by default
    if (ini_get("arg_separator.output") != "&") {
        $sep_changed = true;
        $orig_sep = ini_get("arg_separator.output");
        ini_set("arg_separator.output", "&");
    }
    $post_vars = http_build_query($params);
    if ($sep_changed) {
        ini_set("arg_separator.output", $orig_sep);
    }

    $payload = "POST " . $this->apiUrl["path"] . "?" . $this->apiUrl["query"] . "&method=" . $method . " HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    $payload .= "Host: " . $host . "\r\n";
    $payload .= "User-Agent: MCAPI/" . $this->version . "\r\n";
    $payload .= "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $payload .= "Content-length: " . strlen($post_vars) . "\r\n";
    $payload .= "Connection: close \r\n\r\n";
    $payload .= $post_vars;

    ob_start();
    if ($this->secure) {
        $sock = fsockopen("ssl://" . $host, 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
    } else {
        $sock = fsockopen($host, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
    }
    if (!$sock) {
        $this->errorMessage = "Could not connect (ERR $errno: $errstr)";
        $this->errorCode = "-99";
        ob_end_clean();
        return false;
    }


    $response = "";

    fwrite($sock, $payload);
    stream_set_timeout($sock, $this->timeout);
    $info = stream_get_meta_data($sock);
    while ((!feof($sock)) && (!$info["timed_out"])) {
        $response .= fread($sock, $this->chunkSize);
        $info = stream_get_meta_data($sock);
    }   
    fclose($sock);
    ob_end_clean();
```

`var_dump($info);`
this return array(7) { ["timed_out"]=> bool(false) ["blocked"]=> bool(true) ["eof"]=> bool(false) ["stream_type"]=> string(14) "tcp_socket/ssl" ["mode"]=> string(2) "r+" ["unread_bytes"]=> int(0) ["seekable"]=> bool(false) }

`var_dump($response);`
this returns "http://HTTP/1.0 302 Moved Temporarily Server: AkamaiGHost Content-Length: 0 Location: https://us8.api.mailchimp.com/1.3/?output=php&method=listSubscribe Date: Fri, 10 Aug 2018 21:51:06 GMT Connection: close"

Comment: better use `CURL`, which supports temporary `302` by option `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`. for a temporary fix, you could just update the base-location to the location provided in the `302` header.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For me setting `$this->secure = true` didn't do the job because of the class' **__construct()**

```
function __construct($apikey, $secure=false) {
    $this->secure = $secure;
    $this->apiUrl = parse_url("https://api.mailchimp.com/" . $this->version . "/?output=php");
    $this->api_key = $apikey;
}
```

So when you instantiate the class with just the API key `$secure` is false by default.

Fix:

`$api = new MCAPI($apiKey, true);`

Hope this helps any of you guys using a 7 year old repository ( myself included )...

Comment: Thanks for your help I really solved my problem using your solution in mailchimps API for version 1.3 so thanks again.

Comment: Good on them but has there been an announcement or anything regarding this does anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

It appeared they don't allow none secure connections anymore, this is why request was redirected and the php wrapper I used silently passed without any error and not adding e-mail to Mailchimp. Solution if to simply set $this->secure to `true`.